# How to force Nautilus to check file extension before file content for default application

Tags: gnome, nautilus, mime-type

Nautilus first checks the file content before the file extension to decide which mime type to use.

I have a bunch of raw file with different first few bytes: Nautilus doesn't follow the type association based on file extension but uses the first few bytes of the file. That leads to opening a wrong application for my raw data.

Is there a way to force nautilus to check file extension first?